# Flatten Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Is it possible to get only de values for an Eloquent query.

For example:

```
$data =Model::where('status', 1)->get();
```

it returns key - value object, what I want is get only the values.

The purpose of this is to get the data from the table to be inserted in sqlite.

Like this:

executeSql('INSERT INTO table VALUES (?,?)', ['val1', 'val2', ...])

Comment: Can you provide example and reason for doing this ? Even ["elem1","elem2"] have key "0" and "1"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`flatten`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-flatten) collection:

```
$data = Model::where('status', 1)->get();
$flattened_data = $data->flatten();
```

Now you can retrieve the values:

```
$flattened_data->all();
```

Comment: That methods returns the key-val object :(

Comment: So you want array? Use `toArray()`